Oculus Rift DK2 Ubuntu 22.04
I got myself an Oculus Rift DK2, so I connected my DK2 to my PC via Display port (PC) to HDMI (DK2) and it actually it works... kinda.
Quick note, it's the built in display port the PC is Dell Optiplex 9020 and it uses a built-in AMD graphics card (that is what Ubuntu says /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf)
I can see the boot screen where Ubuntu spins around. I can see it as if it's the second monitor, but as soon as I boot into the actual GUI, for the Ubuntu, the headset turns off, the LED no longer burns blue, but is now yellow and nothing happens.
Side note: I did happen to see an error that says *Error* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 20 or similar of a kind, still I couldn't come up with any solution to that issue either.
If I force my PC boot with only the HMD then the boot screen goes OK, displays in the VR glasses, but then I only get the black screen until I connect my VGA monitor.
The cable works, as I can connect any other regular HDMI monitor, and it will work as primary or secondary monitor if needed even after booting up into the graphical interface of the OS.
I tried everything, I installed OpenHMD and I got it working actually, the head position works fine, so the SDK works and it can communicate with the headset, but I can't get the desktop to show up at all.
